# how to track user activities on a web application

Tags: node.js

I wanted to know how we can track all user activities in a application using node.js

for example, 
after user login, user might delete some data, upload some files, edit some details, etc. How can we store all this and show user, what activity was performed on which date.

Is there any module that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

This might not the accurate answer to your query but still this can be an way to log user activity.

If you are using nodejs backend just defined an middleware for very activity user performs for example below.

```
// this is middleware
user_middleware_logger=(res,req,next)=>{ console.log(res['user_id']); next() }

// actual routes
app.post('add_user', **user_middleware_logger**, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('delete')
})

app.pust('update', **user_middleware_logger**, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('updated')
})
```